# Android Navigation Dynamic-feature module deeplink not working

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-deep-link, dynamic-feature-module

I'm using jetpack navigation component with single activity structure and dynamic feature module approach to separate application modules.
I don't want make modules on-demand for now, so all of them will install on installation base app module.
In my app module navigation XML I have 4 include-dynamic parts that refers to each dynamic modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_navigation_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/featurePaydarNavGraph">

<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/featurePaydarNavGraph"
    app:graphResName="feature_paydar_nav_graph"
    app:moduleName="feature_paydar" />

<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/featurePawintoNavGraph"
    app:graphResName="feature_pawinto_nav_graph"
    app:moduleName="feature_pawinto" />

<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/featureToolsNavGraph"
    app:graphResName="feature_tools_nav_graph"
    app:moduleName="feature_tools" />

<include-dynamic
    android:id="@+id/featureServicesNavGraph"
    app:graphResName="feature_services_nav_graph"
    app:moduleName="feature_services" />

</navigation>
```

Some parts of modules have connections for example in tools module it has QR code ability that reads and will navigate to other fragment in other module, so I create a deeplink in second module to make navigation easier with Navigation-Component `NavManager`.

The problem is if I didn't enter second module before calling deeplink from first module it makes application crashes that says couldn't find deeplink, but when I entered second module and then call deeplink from first module it will work fine without any problem. So I think that something should be triggered to make navigation understand dynamic module deeplinks.

I know google mentioned in the end of the following link (Limitations section) that deeplink not supported for dynamic-module yet:

[Navigation-dynamic Limitations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic#limitations)

So I figured out that it works when target module was open before calling it's deeplink from other module and won't work when not opened before.